# Compiler Optimization on C# if/else

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I don't have too much knowledge of compilers and how .Net optimizes the generated machine code but would like to understand the following scenario:

```
    class AnyClass
    {
        public bool anyFlag;
        AnyClass()
        {
            anyFlag = true;
        }

        public void Action()        
        {
            if(anyFlag)
                 //Perform Certain Actions
        }
    }
```

anyFlag does not change throughout the scope of the program. Will the compiler generate MIL/machine code for Action method? If so will it have the if check in there?

Comment: I guess you meant private bool anyFlag;

Comment: Why does a single if matter to you that much?

Comment: I asked the question more from an understanding perspective. And I guess it does matter after all :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case the compiler won't filter the if statement because your anyFlag is public (so it can be changed from multiple places) and because the value is only is set in the consctructor the compiler also doesn't now this value until runtime.

The following code does what you want:

```
static void MyFunc()
{
    const bool flag = true;

    string s = null;
    if (flag)
    {
        s = "a";
    }
    else
    {
        s = "b";
    }
}
```

If you insert this code in Visual Studio you will see a generated warning stating that s="b"; will never be reached and this code will be optimized out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the compiler will generate the IL. Since you could later user reflection or Emit to call that method or alter the value of `anyFlag`, it retains it. You can show this by disassembling the produced executable file using [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx), which comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: But the IL isn't really important when it comes to performance, the JIT-generated native code is.

Comment: Sure, but since the JITer's optimisations are a black-box, with no specification on this matter. You just have to trust that it's doing its job. What's more important is that the IL is generated and that the developer can access the code if they need to.

Comment: @Polynomial `You can show this by disassembling the produced executable file using ildasm`, Just try the above code(with `const bool`) yourself.

Comment: @Polynomial What do you mean, no specification? The CLI spec says how each IL instruction should behave, although it doesn't specify exactly what assembly instructions should be used. Similarly, the C# spec says how each C# construct should behave, but not exactly what IL instructions should be used. (It doesn't even say you have to use IL!)

Comment: @L.B. Sure, if it's `const bool` it'll get omitted. His code doesn't say `const bool` though.

Comment: @svick - You misunderstood. Of course the behaviour of each instruction is defined under strict specification (ECMA-334). What I'm saying that there's no specification as to how the JIT compiler *optimises* the IL into native code. It's a total black-box job in that respect. You can't guarantee whether the JIT compiler will read the IL and cache native instructions, or skip reading the IL completely because it never gets called.